# Vue 3: did not understand the error when trying to go to another page

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I use a `vue-router` for navigation. When I had a project on `Vue2`, everything worked fine. I transferred the project to `Vue3`, fixed what I could, but now there is such an error, and I can not figure out how to fix it
[image]

Comment: The error message seems pretty obvious - you are trying to access a property 'type' on a null var. But - i'd guess without more context it's impossible to assist in fixing this.

Comment: I understand the essence of the error, I do not understand in which file this error

Comment: from what I understand, it has to do with Hot Reload